# validating html form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I want to validate this form, I'm trying to do it with `document.getElementByid();` but it is not working can anyone help me with this and why it is not going the way that I'm trying.

```
 <form name="simple" action="POST">

            <label for="name">
                Name:
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="demo" class="form-control" onsubmit="validate();"><br>

            <label for="email">
                E-mail:
            </label>
            <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control"><br>

            <label for="pwd">
                Password:
            </label>
            <input type="password" id="pwd" class="form-control"><br>

            <label for="phone">
                Phone:
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="phone" class="form-control"><br>

            <input type="button" type="submit" value ="Submit" class="form-control" onclick="validate();" >

            <input type="button" type="reset" value ="Reset" class="form-control">

        </form>
        <script>


        function validate()
    {
        var txt = document.getElementById("demo");
        alert(txt);
        if(txt == " " || txt == null)
        {
            alert("Name can't be left blank");
        }

    }
        </script>
```

Comment: Where's your opening form tag? That's where onsubmit should be

Comment: no the problem is not with that the problem mainly is - when we input data from the input name field it prints the data but when I submit the with blank name field it doesn't give any output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the value of a field, you have to access the `.value` field of the element, like so: `document.getElementById('demo').value`.

In order to catch the `submit` event, you must set the `onsubmit` function on the form, like so:

```
document.getElementById("myform").onsubmit = validate;
```

Inside the validate function, you have to call `return false;` in case the input is invalid:

```
if (txt === null || txt.trim() === '') {
    alert("Name can't be left blank");
    return false;
}
```

Also, if you're doing validation, look into the `pattern` and `required` attributes of the `input` element. All modern browsers will respect the rules you set with these attributes, and you wouldn't have to manually validate it.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: even with document.getElementById("demo").value it doesn't work. and I want to validate with js not html.

Comment: I edited the above answer, with extra info on how to catch the submit event (so you can prevent or accept it).

Comment: It now also checks that the input is actually empty (before, it only detected if the input was a single space character).

Comment: thanks this worked can you pls explain me why we have used txt.trim() ??

Comment: The `.trim()` function removes blank spaces (and other similar characters, like newlines) from both sides of a string. So if the user types one or many blank spaces, this will still register as an empty string.

Any string containing only spaces (`"          "`) will become an empty string (""), and it will match the condition in the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

The @user337554 is correct, I just want to show you another approach, it's valid to say when we are taking care about forms/fields handling.

Using JavaScript in it's traditional form, you can mind in using the form's `onsubmit` event to trigger the validation and wait it's return to proceed or not with the POST / GET you want.

The DOM node structure enable you to access fields by it's respective names using something like `document.form_name.field_name`.

In my example I've passed the form itself as parameter to the validation function, so you will handle it as the native DOM form object with all it's features and children.

Hope it helps you in minding about possibilities in your code, I like that because I can make it cleaner and I can use the DOM tree instead of millions `getElementByID`.

You can run the code below, it works:

```js
/**
 * Triggered by the form's onsubmit event
 */
function validate(form)
{
  console.info("Beginning the validation..");
  
  // Validating the fields by the DOM nodes sequence from form to input names
  if(form.demo.value == "")
  {
      alert("Name can't be left blank");
      return false; // Quit the POST
  }

  if(form.email.value == "")
  {
      alert("E-mail can't be left blank");
      return false; // Quit the POST
  }

  if(form.pwd.value == "")
  {
      alert("Password can't be left blank");
      return false; // Quit the POST
  }

  if(form.phone.value == "")
  {
      alert("Phone can't be left blank");
      return false; // Quit the POST
  }
  
  console.info("Finished!");
  
  // Form is OK
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" name="simple" action="POST" onsubmit="return validate(this)">

  <label for="name">
      Name:
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="demo" name="demo" class="form-control"><br>

  <label for="email">
      E-mail:
  </label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control"><br>

  <label for="pwd">
      Password:
  </label>
  <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" class="form-control"><br>

  <label for="phone">
      Phone:
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control"><br>

  <!--
  IT'S WRONG, YOU HAVE 2 TYPES HERE, USE SUBMIT TO INTERCEPT THE EVENT
  <input type="button" type="submit" value ="Submit" class="form-control" >
  -->
  <input type="submit" value ="Submit" class="form-control" >

  <input type="button" type="reset" value="Reset" class="form-control">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
function validate() {
  txt = document.getElementById("demo");
  alert(txt);
  if(txt.value.trim() == "" || txt.value == null)
  {
      alert("Name can't be left blank");
  }
}
```

Note: The keyword `var` is not present before the `txt` variable. The `value` fetches the value of the input field with id `demo`. The `trim()` function trims the leading/trailing spaces to ensure the input is not just white space character/s.